# how to apply duplicated function to the columns of a data frame

Tags: r

This seem simple enough I couldn't find the answer after a few searches and I don't know what I am doing wrong yet.  Specifically I want to know if the `MARGIN` argument should allow me to check for duplicated columns with `duplicated`.

This is may code:

```
dim(b)
    [1]  59 130
duplicated(b, MARGIN = 2)
     [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
    [14] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
    [27] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
    [40] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
    [53] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 duplicated(b, MARGIN = 1)
     [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
    [14] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
    [27] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
    [40] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
    [53] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Changing `MARGIN` from 1 to 2 has no effect, each time I get 59 results for the 59 rows.  I am tying to find the simplest way to remove duplicated columns, and came across `duplicated`. I thought duplicated should work since in the documentation it mentions the margin argument `MARGIN    the array margin to be held fixed: a single integer.`  But apparently I don't understand that yet.

Please elaborate, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MARGIN` argument only works with the array method of `duplicated()`, and not with the data frame method.  But you can use

```
b[!duplicated(c(b))]
```

to remove duplicated columns of a data frame.  `c()` is used to remove the "data.frame" class, turning `b` into a list.  And the default method of `duplicated()` works on lists.  See `help(duplicated)` for more.